# Best practice for running bash commands through REST endpoint

Tags: node.js, bash, nginx, npm, timeout

So I've built a website (using NodeJS) that runs couple bash commands through HTTP query in the server and sometimes I get timeout (server is on Nginx) I am looking for best practices to optimize the execution time, notice that I run the following tasks:

- copy 3 files from a template folder to a newly created folder
- running npm install command (this is the one that takes long to run)
- creating a new nginx conf file and adding it to sites-enabled directory
- generating a Let's Encrypt certificate to support HTTPS for Nginx
- creating logs file for access and error for nginx
- running pm2 start against the nodejs file copied from the template folder

Is there any way to optimize the npm install command or any best practice to run long commands without getting 504 timeout error

Comment: Is there any way you could split the process into multiple requests?

Comment: I figured this out through having npm packages pre installed, and then I realized my problem was the bash script stuck somewhere, I got it solved now but I'm still looking out why it gets stuck